# ¿ Cómo cambiar color de mi objeto cada cierto tiempo en Unity?

Tags: unity3d

¿ Cómo hago para que mi objeto cada 2 segundos cambie de color automaticamente mediante Script? Los materiales que tengo son : verde, rojo y azul.

Yo creía que era así con `GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color` pero me da error y nada... solo quiero que mi objeto cambie color cada 2 segundos, a los que tengo definidos, en ese orden.

Answer (score 1):

La clave está en usar una corrutina (hay más formas de hacerlo, pero esta me parece la más sencilla y "limpia"). Puedes modificar el método `Start()` del script y convertirlo en una como verás a continuación:

```
// Guardamos todos los colores posibles en un array
private Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.Green, Color.Red, Color.Blue };

private IEnumerator Start()
{
    int i = 0;            

    while (true)
    {
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[i];
        i++;

        if (i == colors.Length)
        {
            i = 0;
        }

        // Pausamos el método durante dos segundos
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

para acceder al color de un material a través del Mesh Renderer.
Debes tener en cuenta que este admite mas de un material por objeto.
Pero si tu objeto tiene un solo material y deseas acceder al color entonces prueba esto:

```
//JavaScript
var color1 : Color;

gameObject.GetComponent(MeshRenderer).materiasl[0].color = color1;
```

Con eso accedes al primer material de tu objeto y le cambias el color por el color1 que definas en el Inspector.